# Reusable Modal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have data

```js
const data  = [
      {
         id: "React",
        img: "https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/react-2.svg",
       info: "React is the most popular JavaScript library and is used by Facebook, Instagram, Netflix, Airbnb, Uber Eats, and many more.",
       data: [{"React Hooks": {
        description: "React Hooks is a new addition in React 16.8. It 
       lets you use state and other React features without writing a 
       class."},
      }, 
      {"React Redux": {
        description: "React Redux is the official React binding for 
        Redux. It lets your React components read data from a Redux 
        store, and dispatch actions to the store to update data."}
        }]},{..}]
```

I also have buttons with `set name` and `id` similar to `data.[0].id`. I would like to click button and display modal corresponding to button.

Questions:

1. How do I get Modal component to extract this data according to button/element clicked? //I suspect an API call, or maybe props.
2. Shall I add multiple modal components underneath each button? // I am thinking yes.
3. Where can I find out more on this topic? // I have been at it for
   hours and a right direction would be great.

Further clarification zone:

```js
import Modal from './Modal'

export function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)

  return (
   <>
    <button id={React}>
      React
      <Modal open={isOpen}/>
    </button>

    <button id={Express}>
    Express
      <Modal open={isOpen}/>
    </button>
   </>
)
}
```

Modal Component

```js
Import data from './data.js'

export default Modal({open}) {
  if(!open) return null

  return (
   <div className='overlay'>
     <div className='modalContainer'></div>
   </div>
)
}
```

Comment: So your plan is: You have buttons that correspond to elements in your `data` array. When clicked, they open a modal to display `info` maybe? Have you tried something like: When a button is clicked, set some state (like `id`) and in your `render` function you show modal data based on that `id`?

Comment: FYI it would be MUCH easier to help if you also include the rest of the javascript - maybe in a codesandbox link or jsfiddle, or something similar

Comment: I have added some extra code, I hope it's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) library by installing it as

```
npm i react-modal
```

into your React project and use it like:

```
import Modal from "react-modal";
Modal.setAppElement("#root");
```

If you want to have multiple buttons, you can use your `data` array and map through it like

```
{data.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIsModalOpen(true);
              setPattern(index);
            }}
          >
            {item.id}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
```

By doing so you are setting also pattern to which index you want. You can then show the modal depending on which pattern you have by:

```
<Modal
        isOpen={modalIsModalOpen}
        style={modalCustomStyles}
        onRequestClose={() => setIsModalOpen(false)}
      >
        <p>id is {data[pattern].id}</p>
        <img src={data[pattern].img} alt={data[pattern].img} width="100" />
        <p>{data[pattern].info}</p>
      </Modal>
```

You can find working prototype at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-sunset-vofru6?file=/src/App.js:42-74).